# Seperate DateTime to Date using talend

Tags: talend

I would like to separate DateTime to Date using talend. 
the DateTime column type is in Timestamp without timezone type and the Date column type is date.

I have entered

```
TalendDate.getDate("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", row1.datetime)
```

at the middle column for TMap.

I have entered

```
TalendDate.getDate("dd-MM-yyyy",Var.getTimestamp)
```

at the output.

However I got this error message:
"Detail Message: The method getDate(String) in the type TalendDate is not applicable for the arguments (String, Date)".

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The function `getDate` will accept only one parameter which is the pattern the date need to be displayed and moreover, `TalendDate.getDate("dd-MM-yyyy")` will return current date in mentioned pattern, which is the result would be

`10-03-2017 // Since Today's date is 10th March 2017.`

In order to format the date you have, there is another function that talend provides, which is

**`TalendDate.formatDate("dd-MM-yyyy",row1.datetime)`**

Say if `row1.datetime` has value as `"2017-02-23 12:12:12"`, then the result would be

`23-02-2017`

Hope this would solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and sorry for the late reply!
I tried your method but it shows "Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to Date."

Comment: Are you assigning the result to a `date` object?